# fx money error in react

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use [money](https://www.npmjs.com/package/money) with react?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import fx from 'money' // import { fx } from 'money'

[...]

const pounds = fx(1.99).from("USD").to("GBP");
```

> Uncaught fx error

Im looking for something that coverts x currency to x currency.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be connected to React anyhow

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/openexchangerates/money.js/issues/8) instead

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: No, only pure javascript/es6

Comment: @Flying Ok, I've made the edit.

Comment: How did you set the exchange rates? http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/#fx.rates

Comment: @AnikoLitvanyi <shocked-face> Yes! Thanks! Ive just set it and it worked. I believe this would be useful to someone. Add your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the exchange rates as it is recommended in the documentation:

[openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/#fx.rates](http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/#fx.rates)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import fx from 'money' // import { fx } from 'money'

[...]

someFunc() {
  fx.base = "USD";
    fx.rates = {
        "EUR" : 0.745101, // eg. 1 USD === 0.745101 EUR
        "GBP" : 0.647710, // etc...
        "USD" : 1,        // always include the base rate (1:1)
        /* etc */
    }
  const pounds = fx(1.99).from("USD").to("GBP");
  return pounds
}
```